# Jersey2 Spring Tomcat load time weaver not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, aspectj, jersey-2.0

I am using hibernate as JPA provider in a JAX-RS (Jersey2) application with spring.
I am trying to autowire some business services inside a JPA entity. I have declared a loader class in the context.xml

```
<Context path="/">
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
</Context>
```

and copied the spring-instrument.tomcat.4.1.17.jar to the tomcat/libs

I have also added:

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

to my applicationContext.xml

The aop.xml is located under resources/META-INF/aop.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo -XmessageHandlerClass:org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJWeaverMessageHandler">
        <include within="com.appolica.server.musyme.*"/>
    </weaver>

</aspectj>
```

I have tried both web 3.0 and 2.5 configurations. Also both tomcat 8+ and 7+.

The entity class is annotated with @Configurable.

The only thing that I get in the log is

```
Using a reflective load-time weaver for class loader: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
```

I have all of the possible aspectj and spring aop dependencies:

```
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.6'
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.6'
runtime 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.6'

compile 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.1.7.RELEASE'
compile "cglib:cglib:2.2"

compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.7.RELEASE"

compile 'org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:4.1.7.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-instrument:4.1.7.RELEASE'
```

I am really desperate because I have tried everything that I could think of/find on the internet and the services never get autowired.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess have more details about your config files and code.. but with only this.. Can I ask if you have the

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..... "/>
```

in your *applicationContext.xml* file?

Comment: Yes,      <context:component-scan base-package="com.appolica.server.musyme.images.model"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.appolica.server.musyme.*"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.appolica.server.musyme.series"/>

Comment: There is a document issue in Tomcat regarding the Time Weave Load. It depends about your Tomcat version can work or not. Latest documentation as far as I have read advise not use the Spring Instrument and use the ones that comes in Tomcat 8.

Comment: [Here a link to the issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11446) the following text seems more clear...
`Note: The InstrumentableClassLoader mentioned in SPR-10788 does not exist neither in Tomcat 7.0.52 nor its current 7.0.x trunk (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk) but only in the main trunk (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk).`

Comment: I don't tried to configure that in version greater than 7.0.52-1ubuntu... but in your case I will go direct to use Tomcat 8 and use the functions there. [as reference](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10788)